# Install react component in Angular project via NPM

Tags: reactjs, angular, vue.js, npm, web-component

I have a component made with react. build using babel : @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/polyfill
and It's published to NPM

The comonent is working well on any other react project, But How can I make it work on Angular project?

[image: Here's my component]
Here's my component, It's imported as a function

[image]
and here is the result of printing

So how can I make this component work here in angular?

Comment: It's the same with any pair of frameworks. Mount React component to DOM element that belongs to Angular wrapper component

Comment: You can't just import a React component into an Angular project and expect Angular to know how to use it.  You would have to wrap the React component in its own React 'app' as such, something like - https://thalava.com/how-to-use-react-web-components-in-angular